# What must I do to enable newly created class schemas to be added as new objects in LDAP?

Tags: ldap, active-directory

I am using ADAM ADSI Edit. I have created a new class schema in the Schema on this LDAP server. However, when I go into LDAP and pick an OU, right-click, and select 'New -> Object...' the newly added class isn't one of the available options. In fact, not all of the class schemas are available in this menu, but some of them are.

Note that under the ADAM ADSI Edit tree the Schema appears as a server icon and the LDAP appears as another server icon (both on the same level). All of the available 'New Object' options in the 'LDAP' are class schemas in the 'Schema', but the available options are only a subset of the total class schemas in 'Schema'.

How do I enable a class schema to be an option in the New Object wizard of LDAP?

Comment: @RyanRies 'defaultHidingValue' is <Not Set> and 'showInAdvancedViewOnly' is FALSE

Comment: Change defaultHidingValue to FALSE and see if that helps.

Comment: @RyanRies nada, though most of the available options have this set to FALSE, a few don't have a value either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the possSuperiors field in your classSchema to make sure organizationalUnit is there.

Hope that helps!